# Finding average of a set of data within a table between different ranges in Excel 2016

Tags: excel

In my spreadsheet, i am trying to determine the average of a set of data in a table between 0-0.5 , 0.5-1 , 1-1.5 and 1.5 up to 2.
the formula that i'm using is :

```
=AVERAGEIFS(All Data, All Data, CONCATENATE(">",0), All Data, CONCATENATE("<=",0.5)))
```

However this formula fails.
i have a feeling that i need to use AND function but i dunno where to use it. if it's possible i want to roundup the average value to a 3 decimals.

[image: Image of my spreadsheet]

Thank you heaps

UPDATE:

So i added the dollar signs to my formula and it perfectly worked. Now i just need to ROUNDUP the result in 3 decimals. I don't know where to place ROUNDUP function in the below formula.

```
 =AVERAGEIFS($A$1:$T$20,$A$1:$T$20,CONCATENATE(">",G24),$A$1:$T$20,CONCATENATE("<=",G25))
```

Comment: The formula in your image is different from that in your post.

Comment: The formula in your picture should work; the formula in your post cannot work since your range argument name `ALL DATA` is not a legal name (it contains a space).  However, there is no simple way to get your screen shot into a worksheet, so trouble shooting is not possible.  Either include a text representation of your data that demonstrates the problem; or upload the file to a public file sharing site (that does **NOT** require registration for us to download) and post a link here.

Comment: You should be using absolute addressing for the table range in your formula, but that should not result in a `#DIV/0` error, ordinarily.

Comment: See my edited response.  Glad, although a bit surprised, that the addressing mode was the only issue.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Looking at the formula in your screenshot, you are using relative addressing.  Hence your table reference will change as you fill down the formula.  Use absolute addressing instead:

```
H25: =AVERAGEIFS($A$1:$T$20,$A$1:$T$20,CONCATENATE(">",G24),$A$1:$T$20,CONCATENATE("<=",G25))
```

To roundup to 3 decimal places, you would wrap your entire formula with that function:

```
H25: =ROUNDUP(AVERAGEIFS($A$1:$T$20,$A$1:$T$20,CONCATENATE(">",G24),$A$1:$T$20,CONCATENATE("<=",G25)),3)
```

***Note:*** some people say ROUND**UP** when they mean ROUND.  Excel has different functions for ROUND and ROUNDUP.

Comment: Thank you very much for your help. To be honest i was shocked when i found out the problem is just the dollar signs. I was spending hours to do this part. I am new to excel to program and it is taking me hours to do an easy formula !!

Comment: Like learning a new language, it will get easier with time and practice. And computer languages, unlike human languages, are very unforgiving of even minor errors. You may mark my response as the answer by selecting the check mark near the upper left.  Thank you.

Comment: Do you mind if i ask for your help for the future questions? I need someone to help me.

Comment: There is no simple way to direct questions only to me.  To get a better idea of how this forum works, you should know that we can help you with complex formulas or code you are trying to develop. Start by taking the [2-minute tour](https://stackoverflow.com/tour). Then read the HELP topics for [How do I Ask a Good Question](http://stackoverflow.com/help/how-to-ask), and also [How to create a Minimal, Complete, and Verifiable example](http://stackoverflow.com/help/mcve).  If I am available, and your question is in my competence, I will respond unless someone has already posted a good answer.

Answer (score 0):

What I would do is compile your data set in one column, give the column a heading and then use the filter function to sort the data in the thresholds you require (data tab>Filter). Click the arrow next to your newly created heading>number filters>between and then choose the range (e.g. 0-0.5). This should then retrieve all the values within this range. Highlight all of the data and copy it to a new spreadsheet, or the same one-whichever you prefer- and use the =AVERAGE function to obtain the average within this range.

Alternatively, you can use the pivot table function available in the 'Insert' tab. Add your data to the 'Columns' and 'Values' field. Right click the cell underneath 'Column Labels'>Group> Starting at 0, Ending at 2.5, By 0.5. Right click a cell in the third row and choose summarize values by average.

I hope this helps.

regards,

Monray